# Cassandra - enable row cache then got a lot of "GC Pauses greater than 200 ms"

Tags: performance, cassandra

I have a table with about 1 million record, most reads (over 95%), table schema :

```
CREATE TABLE ams_table (
    projectid text,
    tagk text,
    tagv text,
    metricid bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY (projectid, tagk, tagv, metricid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (tagk ASC, tagv ASC, metricid ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

read the table is very frequent, the number of requests in half, duration time for 70%, causing a high CPU usage. so I thought that it's perfect for use row cache.

one record have 4 field, less than 100 byte, so I thought that the entire table does not occupy more than 100MB memory.

so, alter table, rows_per_partition to 'ALL', cache all record.

```
ALTER TABLE ams.tbl_tags_with_metricid WITH caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'ALL' } ;
```

modify cassandra.yaml, set row_cache_size_in_mb to 128M.

```
row_cache_size_in_mb : 128
```

nodetool info, hit rate almost 0.945, until now everything's just fine.
but soon, I saw that the CPU usage is higher.
check system.log, get a lot of GC Pauses greater than 200 ms. like this.

```
WARN  [Native-Transport-Requests-10] 2017-11-22 08:55:39,793 SelectStatement.java:377 - Aggregation query used without partition key
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-11-22 08:55:40,553 GCInspector.java:284 - ParNew GC in 204ms.  CMS Old Gen: 11955784424 -> 12032443672; Par Eden Space: 671088640 -> 0; Par Survivor Space: 77459760 -> 83886080
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-11-22 08:55:43,551 GCInspector.java:284 - ParNew GC in 213ms.  CMS Old Gen: 12264670920 -> 12341517200; Par Eden Space: 671088640 -> 0; 
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-11-22 08:55:45,673 GCInspector.java:284 - ParNew GC in 221ms.  CMS Old Gen: 12354581144 -> 12432569616; Par Eden Space: 671088640 -> 0; 
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-11-22 08:55:46,186 GCInspector.java:284 - ParNew GC in 217ms.  CMS Old Gen: 12248728592 -> 12343417080; Par Eden Space: 671088640 -> 0; 
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-11-22 08:55:47,799 GCInspector.java:284 - ParNew GC in 354ms.  CMS Old Gen: 11967866640 -> 12058730544; Par Eden Space: 671088640 -> 0; 
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-11-22 08:55:48,242 GCInspector.java:284 - ParNew GC in 204ms.  CMS Old Gen: 11940028704 -> 11987653704; Par Eden Space: 671088640 -> 0;
```

cassandra 3.9, deployed in kubernetes container(cpu 8 core, memory 32G), free memory about 10G.

And I try to alter table, 'rows_per_partition' to '3000', so "GC Pauses greater than 200 ms" was disappear, but hit rate is lower and lower, and CPU usage become the same as before.

Comment: Provide the output for this nodetool command:
      ``` nodetool tablestats [keyspace].ams_table
      ```

Comment: I have a confusion about this data model. Why have you used all the columns in the primary key? What are your read queries?

You said 95% is read I assume deletes or inserting null columns (generation of lots of tombstone) or updates operations are not concerning factor here. Is my assumption right?